# Yii2 getting columns name from SQL command when result == null

Tags: mysql, yii2

If you get the following code :

```
  $DBConnection = 
    CreateNewDBConnection(Yii::$app->get('db_cdh'),$aDatabaseName);
    $DBConnection->open();
    $command = $DBConnection->createCommand($aQuery);
    $queryres = $command->queryAll();
```

If there is result from the query, I get an array, like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [name] => 2.6.084.545
        [xdim+2] => 70
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => 2.5.102.030
        [xdim+2] => 60
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => 2.5.141.560
        [xdim+2] => 80
    )

)
```

But if the result of the query is empty, i get an empty array.
 How is it possible to get the columns name ?

The reason why I'm asking this, it's because I'm asking queries to multiple DBs and some have results (1 or more lines) and otherd not. The system almost works, but the grid view parse only the first line to find the columns to display. So depending on the order result across the multiple DB, the grid view display the columns or not, depending what come first ....

Any help welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the column names using [**yii\db\TableSchema**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-tableschema.html) and use them afterwards:

```
$columns = [];
if (empty($queryres)) {
    $columns = $DBConnection->getTableSchema('your_table_name')->getColumnNames();
}
```

Comment: I don't know the table either, it's complex queries edited by the user.

Comment: Then, if the result of your first query is empty you can run the same query without the WHERE statement with LIMIT 1 and take the column names from there.